# Auto fill date that increments after every 4 rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have data as shown below. All the data has the same date in the BILLDATE column (e.g., 01/04/2015; that's dd/mm/yyyy).  I want to adjust the dates on these 70 records in a particular month so that after every 4 records, the date will be incremented to the next day automatically, as shown in the Output column.

For example, for the first 4 rows, the date will be 01/04/2015, and for the next 4 rows the date will be 02/04/2015, and for the next the date will be 03/04/2015, and so on, until 30/04/2015, when all 70 records should be adjusted. I want output like shown in this image.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's easier for people to develop and verify solutions if you provide sample data rather than a picture of data. You can use a web resource like [table generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) or [senseful](https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/) to easily convert a spreadsheet snippet to a text table that you can paste in the question.

Comment: Some key things aren't clear.  You describe incrementing every 4 rows and the 70 records being adjusted by the 30th of the month.  At 4 row increments, it will be adjusted long before that.  The original wording mentions "3 or 4" day increments.  Even at 3 day increments, it will be adjusted before the 30th.  You give no information on "3 or 4", so there's no way for people to develop a solution that reflects any form of that.  Is there some kind of rule or pattern as to which interval gets applied when? Is the formula supposed to figure out when to apply each to meet some objective?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this formula, if your date is in A1, in A2 write:

`=DATE(YEAR($A$1),MONTH($A$1),DAY($A$1)+INT((ROW()-1)/4))`

and drag it down, it will increment the day every 4 rows you can change 4 to 3 or whatever number you need.

[image]