# Is there a formula that we can use to autofill dates but have 10 lines on each weekday date?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Would anyone know a formula we can use to autofill dates but have 10 lines on each weekday dates so then we only have to update the start and end dates? This is needed for time & task management sheet.

Sample sheet

[image]

The closest answer I could find was from this discussion (i just changed increments after every 4 rows to 10 rows as I require): [Auto fill date that increments after every 4 rows](https://superuser.com/questions/1164401/auto-fill-date-that-increments-after-every-4-rows)

But the problem with this formula is that it also includes 10 lines for weekends (i.e. Saturdays & Sundays).

Is there a way to delete the 9 extra lines for Saturdays & Sundays? Or any other formula I can use?

Appreciate any help, thank you in advance.

Comment: your attempt to format the table has resulted in it being really tough to reverse engineer into markdown. If you edit & re-paste your data, then just select it all & hit Ctrl/k, it will be much simpler to read (the formatting is basic but legible that way)

Comment: beware: one problem with the linked discussion is that the resultant dates are tied to the specific (current) row number

Comment: Hi Tetsujin, thank you for pointing that out. I have now taken it out and showed a screenshot instead, hopefully that is clearer and better to understand.

Comment: Hi Yorik, yes I understand. The idea is that we would only have to change 1 row (in this case it should be B1) and everything else follows through, hopefully. Is there a better way to do it then if you don't recommend tying it to a specific row number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in B5 and copy down the entire column:

```
 =IF(B4="","",IF(AND(COUNTIF($B$4:B4,B4)>=10,B4>=$D$1),"",IF(AND(WEEKDAY(B4,2)<6,COUNTIF($B$4:B4,B4)<10),B4,B4+1)))
```

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU! It works perfectly! :-)